# OpenId Connect logout for stateless SSO

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, jwt, openid-connect

I am trying to implement OpenId Connect for SSO in one of my projects. However, I am a bit struggling with the case where I would like to validate OpenId JWT token on Resource Server side to make it stateless. If user tries to logout, authorization Server will know about the user logout (Accordingly OpenId Connect Session Management spec). But how should Authorization Server tell Resource Server that the user's token is not valid anymore? It is a case when user after log out out goes to Resource Server with his OpenId token and gets access. That is weird and I could not find any solution across Internet. Please help me to organize stateless security with central logout.

Comment: I have found two related topics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355808/openid-connect-with-stateless-jwt-tokens and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533285/openid-connection-session-management-can-id-token-be-revoked but non of them answer my question.

Comment: The id_token or access token should be short lived, as the answer you already found says: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32536038/676335
Using short lived access_token, your project must make a call with refresh_token to renew it, and then the authorization server can refuse to give new access_token for logged out user.

Comment: Thank you for response. Unfortunately, it is an Implicit flow (Relying Party is AngularJS application). Accordingly to OpenId Connect spec. for this flow, refresh token should not be used at all, because it is insecure. That is why there are no answers, covering this problem. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Token Introspection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662) endpoint to determine whether the access token passed is valid or not. The resource server can make a call to OP's introspection endpoint to validate the token before giving access to the resource. In order to effectively validate the token, the resource server should :

- Be a registered client with OP and have Same / similar Scope as SPA app (Implicit flow app) to validate the scopes passed to it         and
- Have access to Introspection endpoint

The are more details in the above linked Spec for further understanding.

P.S. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37534066/1371639) that I wrote earlier has some other relevant references.

Comment: Thanks, it is my "Plan B" for now. But if I start to check my tokens in Token Introspection endpoint, it means that I should store info about issued tokens in one central place. It means that system will become stateful, but not stateless. To make this system scalable, I should share user sessions, that I would like to escape. Moreover, for each request from Relaying Party (RP) to Resource Server (RS), RS should send another request to OP, that will affect traffic significantly. Your idea is to make system stateful, but I would like to make it statless using JWT validation or another approach.

Comment: Gentlemen, any ideas? Is it possible to make SSO stateless?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your requirement here. But, can't you use a JWT Access token as a stateless token in your scenario ? This link - http://nordicapis.com/how-to-control-user-identity-within-microservices/ has some information around stateless token exchange. hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, mate, but there is no information in that post about how to revoke stateless JWT for logout. That is really weird. Almost every post about OpenId Connect tells how beautiful JWT are for stateless sessions, but nobody can explain anything about single logout. Refresh tokens sould not be use for JS application. Short TTL of session token leads to bad user experience. It is a shame.

Comment: You cannot revoke a self-contained JWT. This is by design.The expectation is application session manages the applicaiton logout and effective measures were taken to protect all the tokens (SSL , CSRF protection, IDtoken - nonce,iss,etc are met). Reference token can be revoked since the token state is maintained at the OIDC server (either by token revocation endpoint or using any of the session management mechanism mentioned in draft spec - like iframe state communication).

Comment: There is a trade off between network call (refrence token) and stateless sessions(JWT self-contained access token) with some degree of security concern (which is mitigated by issuing Access tokens with limited validity period)

Comment: Thanks, Karthik, for explanation. Let's talk about stateless sessions(JWT self-contained access token), it is eventually my case. If I use tokens with limited validity period, does it mean that user's session should be very short and user should login quite often? (For example: if token's validity period is 2 minutes for security concern mitigating, user must login every 2 minutes as well)?

Comment: Not necessarily.. If you are retrieving an access token via  front-end, you could request a new access token via iframe (behind the scenes) one minute before the current token expires. There are many front-end library implementation for this See - https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki (under silent renew). Users need not login again as long as they have active identity provider session

Comment: It is interesting solution. Could you please provide me a link for OpenId Connect specification, that is describing this as a part of session management. I could not find anything about this on the official site (http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html)

Comment: I could only found how silently obtain access token via refresh token, but it is kind of prohibited way for browser app (Implicit flow). And second question: if it is not a refresh token, what should I send to obtain new access token?

Comment: Hey Alex, I know it's an old thread, but for future references you can use `signinSilent()` (implemented by various libraries like : https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki). I'm more interested by the Single Logout problem. The OP will inform the backend that the user has centrally logged out, but what would be the cleanest way to inform my frontend that I should also logout my user from the app via the browser ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jwt bearer flow, where you can pass ID token/Assertion token to OP in order to generate access token.